# Move contacts from an account to another with app android

Tags: android, contacts, account

I must move some contacts from an account to another with my Samsung Galaxy A5.

I've tried on settings, but i can't do anything usefull, so there are some free andorid apps that do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A similar question is at https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172253/188657. Apparently, applications like [Copy Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alefsoft.copycontacts&showAllReviews=true) or [Easy Backup - Contacts Transfer and Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simpler.backup) can do that.

I could not figure it out, so I simply exported everything into a vcf file that I backed up on my computer, and then I un-linked the account, *de facto* deleting all the contacts related to it. Then, I re-imported the contact using my vcf files.

I believe this approach does not fare well if the account kept is not empty, as it will duplicate all of its entries, but I believe that on some versions of Android you can actually export only the contact of a particular account.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/u/0/preview/all) to do something like this:

- Sign into the source Google account.
- Select More > Export...
- Select Google CSV format (for importing into a Google account)
- Save the file.
- Sign into the destination Google account.
- Select More > Import... Select the file you saved previously, and import.

Credits to Patrick Schroedl over at the [Android Central thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/355404-how-can-i-move-contacts-one-google-account-another.html).

Comment: i have two accounts: outlook.it and an exchange account.

Comment: That should be straightforward. From your first account, go to 'People', then click on 'Manage', then export your contacts. Then sign into your Exchange account & import all the contacts.

Comment: This allows only to move a contact into a Google contact.